# On Bitrise, can I make two workflows independently update separate GitHub checks on the same PR?

Tags: bitrise

When I create a pull request on GitHub, my project kicks off a workflow in Bitrise that only exists to start two other workflows, then it finishes. What I would expect to see in the GitHub pull request checks dialog is three distinct Bitrise checks which are waiting for each workflow to finish (One for the initial short workflow, then two more for the two workflows that are started from this first one). In reality, I only see one check for this initial workflow. This one always succeeds after about 15 seconds because, as I've stated, it does no real work of its own. Is it possible to show distinct checks for all workflows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This one always succeeds after about 15 seconds because, as I've stated, it does no real work of its own.

Move some of the work into this main workflow then add the `Bitrise Wait for Build` step to the end of the workflow ( https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/triggering-builds/trigger-multiple-workflows/ ). This way this main triggered workflow will report the final status back to GitHub and it doesn't have to finish in 15 seconds, it can do real work while it's waiting on the other workflows.